# ENERGY TRANSFER

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, collision

Why does an electron carry half the center of mass energy after undergoing RELATIVISTIC elastic scattering at 90 degress with a proton in the center of mass frame. Is there a reference that you may know to support this claim?

Comment: What makes you think this claim is true?

Comment: I read the following: In the CM frame, the electron's energy after scattering (at 90 degrees) will be essentially half of the center-of mass energy (since this is much larger than the proton or electron rest mass).

Comment: OK, I understand now. The “essentially” is relevant. And the collision needs to be highly relativistic, not just relativistic.